# Need help finding the error

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

I have the following code which contains a run-time error. The code was meant to print out:

Vehicle mode:flight Fuel:propane Max Altitude:10000

Vehicle mode:traversal Fuel:coal Horsepower:5000

I could not find it myself (as I am fairly new to coding) and would like some help if possible.

Thanks.

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HotAirBalloon airbag = new HotAirBalloon(10000);
    Locomotive loco = new Locomotive(5000);

    System.out.println(airbag.toString());
    System.out.println(loco.toString());
}
}

class Vehicle {

String mode, fuel;

public String toString() {
    return "Vehicle Mode:" + mode + " Fuel:" + fuel;
}
}

class HotAirBalloon extends Vehicle {

int maxAltitude;

HotAirBalloon(int _alt) {
    mode = "flight";
    fuel = "propane";
    maxAltitude = _alt;
}
public String toString() {
    return toString() + " Max Altitude:" + maxAltitude;
}

}

class Locomotive extends Vehicle {

int horsePower;
Locomotive(int _hp) {
    mode = "traversal";
    fuel = "coal";
    horsePower = _hp;

}
public String toString() {
    return toString() + " Horsepower:" + horsePower;
}

}
```

Comment: What is your actual output and where does an error occur?

Comment: The output is in the main method and the error occurs at line 37 (sorry I forgot to post lines) at the line that contains this code (    return toString() + " Max Altitude:" + maxAltitude;). What happens is the code keeps repeating at (ahmed.HotAirBalloon.toString(main.java:37)) and gives this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to call the super classes version of the current method you need to add super.toString()

```
//old
return toString() + " Horsepower:" + horsePower;
//new
return super.toString() + " Horsepower:" + horsePower;
```

You also need to do this with your other subclass

When you a method calls itself its called recursion, where a method keeps calling itself until a certain condition.

Comment: You literally saved my life. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This code will do fine. the problem was that you were calling toString() multiple times which was causing a Stack overflow. plus you have to declare a String in parent class vehicle and update it in the child classes with flight mode etc..run the code below:

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HotAirBalloon airbag = new HotAirBalloon(10000);
    Locomotive loco = new Locomotive(5000);

System.out.println(airbag.toString());
System.out.println(loco.toString());
}
}

class Vehicle {
String mode, fuel;
String s;
}

class HotAirBalloon extends Vehicle {

int maxAltitude;

HotAirBalloon(int _alt) {
    mode = "flight";
    fuel = "propane";
    maxAltitude = _alt;
    s= "Vehicle Mode:" + mode + " Fuel:" + fuel;
}
public String toString() {
    return s + " Max Altitude:" + maxAltitude;
}}

class Locomotive extends Vehicle {

int horsePower;
Locomotive(int _hp) {
mode = "traversal";
fuel = "coal";
horsePower = _hp;
s= "Vehicle Mode:" + mode + " Fuel:" + fuel;

}
public String toString() {
return s+ " Horsepower:" + horsePower;
}
}
```